# P&T Matrix Required Col on VZ URL fieldtype not honored

Tags: matrix

I have a matrix fieldtype with a column that has a VZ URL field in it. The column is set to required but you can leave it blank when submitting an entry. Anyone else have this issue or any insight?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be intentional behaviour:

> Please note that VZ Url will not prevent the user from saving their
>   weblog entry if if cannot validate the url—it just warns them. This is
>   intentional, perhaps they are linking to a page they have not yet
>   created, or the site they are linking to is currently down but they
>   know the url is correct. I may add this functionality as an option
>   later on.